# Smooth scrolling jQuery doesn't work with my absolute positioned button

Tags: jquery, html, smooth-scrolling

I am currently using JS SmoothScroll on my main navigation to navigate smoothly around a one page website. You can see it working fine [here](http://www.jamesperrett.co.uk/testsite) on the main navigation. It's called by adding class="scroll" to the link. The script can be seen [here](http://www.jamesperrett.co.uk/testsite/js/smoothscroll.js).

I'm trying to use the same javascript for my 'back to top' feature. At present the back to top feature works fine but it just 'snaps' to top so I'd like it to scroll like my other navigation does.

However, when I add class="scroll" to that link, it stops working altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery script you linked to will only scroll to an element by `name`, and you are using an `id`. Either modify the script to scroll to elements by `id`, or change the top element to have a `name` instead.

```
$('[name="'+this.hash.substring(1)+'"]') //Select elements by name
```

Note that the use of `name` attributes as anchors is generally frowned upon, so I would suggest updating the jQuery to use `id`, and updating all the other anchors on your page to have `id` attributes too.

Comment: Thanks, I had some trouble getting it to work with ID before hence why I used the name attribute, but this makes sense enough for me to have to work through the problems and change it all to id!